# ActiveRecord does not convert array in string to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Prior to Rails **4.2.0**, ActiveRecord would automatically convert a String to the type specified by `serialize`.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :options, Array # Column type: 'text', DB: PostgreSQL
end

class PostTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "assign options" do
    post = Post.new
    post.options = "[1,2,3]" # => "[1,2,3]"
  end
end
```

In Rails **4.2.1**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :options, Array
end

class PostTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "assign options" do
    post = Post.new
    post.options = "[1,2,3]" # ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String.
  end
end
```

I can't find this in the documentation, changelogs. Was this type of String to Array conversion removed or is it a bug? In my use case, I have such a String from params assigned to a model. It works in Rails 4.1.10 but in Rails 4.2.1 it raises `ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch`.

Comment: column data type of `options` in table ?

Comment: :text. Added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which commit between 4.1.10 and 4.2.1 introduced this behaviour but it's **not a bug** as it is well documented [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html). In particular,

> If class_name is specified, the serialized object must be of that class on assignment and retrieval. Otherwise SerializationTypeMismatch will be raised.

Comment: I see. The documentation in Rails 4.2.1 has changed to reflect this behaviour. The on assignment clause is missing. http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.10/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize . So this is as designed then. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know guys how you had it working on 4.2.0, but i've just tested this case with blank 4.2.0 rails app - it fails with SerializationTypeMismatch. Maybe documentation was slightly changed with 4.2.1, but not behavior.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the Rails version, should have been 4.1.10. Thanks for the investigative work.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange because YAMLColumn has been behaving like this for the years. Take a look at [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9637de6b472b05a09fe6d28d973b4729e3ea4615).

Comment: Just narrowed the question around the actual problem.